# Unable to translate GroupBy Union GroupJoin

Tags: entity-framework-core

### Why doesn't [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rpgDzI) work?

I'm trying to use LINQ for a somewhat complicated query.
Here's a simplified version of the LINQ:

```cs
// Query block.
var parentQuery =
    from p in db2.Things
    where p.Parent == null
    
    group p by p.Id into g
    
    select new Temp {
        Id = g.Key.ToString() + "P",
        ParentId = null,
    };

// Reused query block.
var childQuery =
    from c in db2.Things
    where c.Parent != null
    
    // Something with the multiple properties here seems to be the issue.
    group c by new {
        c.Id,
        c.Name,
    } into g
    
    select new Temp {
        Id = g.Key.Id.ToString() + g.Key.Name,
        ParentId = (g.Key.Id - 1).ToString() + "P",
    };

// Combined/main query.
var query =
    from t in parentQuery.Union(childQuery)
    
    join child in childQuery
    on t.Id equals child.ParentId
    into children
    
    select new {
        Id = t.Id,
        Children = children
            .Select(c => new {
                Id = c.Id,
            })
            .AsEnumerable(),
    };
```

The problem seems to come from the multi-property GroupBy in the child query.
When I oversimplify the child query to use one property for the GroupBy,
the query seems to work.

I thought the Union would have allowed the GroupJoin to work
because the combined parent and child rows would be distinct,
but Entity Framework seems to be taking issue.

Notes:

- Using `parentQuery` or `childQuery` instead of the Union works,
  but obviously that means we're missing data.
- Removing the Children property from the output also works,
  but that is required in our output.
- Using `parentQuery` or `childQuery` for both Union arguments works,
  but I assume that Entity Framework is optimizing it away.

The original implementation used FromSql for the parent and child queries.
Entity Framework is happy to compose those blocks.
We'd like to get away from using hardcoded SQL,
but we can look at using Query instead of (abusing) FromSql
if it's a limitation of Entity Framework.

### Could Concat work?

In our particular case both the Union and Concat
set operations yield the same results.
Logically Concat is the intended operation.
If there's a solution (not just an explanation) to the main question,
is there a way we could also use Concat instead of Union?

Comment: The DotNetFiddle link you put gives you a very descriptive error message when run - please indicate which part of it you're having trouble understanding: _"Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection since either parent or the subquery doesn't project necessary information required to uniquely identify it and correctly generate results on the client side..."_

Comment: (Cont.) _"...This can happen when trying to correlate on keyless entity type. This can also happen for some cases of projection before 'Distinct' or some shapes of grouping key in case of 'GroupBy'. These should either contain all key properties of the entity that the operation is applied on, or only contain simple property access expressions."_

Comment: @Dai The `childQuery` is used twice in the main `query`. That's what I meant by reused.

Comment: @Dai I'm having trouble figuring out what specifically is unacceptable. I assume it's something in the GroupBy, but I can't tell specifically what.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `group c by new { c.Id, c.Name } into g` part if there's no aggregation?

Comment: Looks like weird attempt to get `Parent.Children` for two levels. Interesting which `FromSql` you have used before?

Comment: @Dai There is aggregation in the real `childQuery`; the MRE didn't need it to reproduce the problem, so I omitted it for brevity. The `parentQuery` doesn't aggregate, so that one could be rewritten with Distinct, but that's not the problem spot from what I can tell.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It looks weird because the MRE simplifies the actual data. The structure of the `FromSql` child query is `SELECT...FROM (SELECT...FROM...JOIN x3...GROUP BY)...JOIN x3` with some casting, constants, and functions thrown in to meet the `FromSql` type. The actual SQL is too big for a comment, but I can add it to the question if needed--just let me know--it'll just take a bit to clean it up and make it generic.

Comment: Tell me what SQL (or new LINQ) should do? Anyway, you cannot force EF Core to translate query if it has bugs. `Union` is explicit indication of which set of columns is unique. So, their validator is wrong.  `Concat` do not give such indication.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I know I can't force EF Core, but I'd like to understand it better. As far as what it should do, the MRE attempts to do it. In the particular case of the child query, group rows by a few columns, then create an ID/name from concatenating those columns and get some aggregates. It also joins in some other data, but that's pretty straightforward.